# DLL Loading in Windows Programming

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, native-code

I wanted to got a set of API Native'm using GetProcAddressto. in the method that i use first by GetModuleHandle got the considering DLLHandle then the API address that is my desire,is taken by GetProcAddress. it works for functions in ntdll but for user32 and advapi32 GetModuleHandle function returns null value. for solving this problem, what's your suggestion?

```
enter code here

HANDLE Proc = GetCurrentProcess();
HMODULE hNtdll = GetModuleHandle(TEXT("ntdll.dll"));
FARPROC function_address = GetProcAddress(hNtdll, function_name);
```

Comment: Post a complete code snippet that shows how you are using `LoadLibrary` and `GetModuleHandle`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`GetModuleHandle()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) requires the DLL to already be loaded:

> Retrieves a module handle for the specified module. **The module must have been loaded by the calling process.**

*ntdll.dll* will always be loaded but *user32.dll* and *advapi32.dll* are not necessarily loaded by default. Based on your description it sounds as though the code calls `GetModuleHandle()` first, which will fail if the DLL is not already loaded (check the value of [`GetLastError()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the event of failure).

Use `LoadLibrary()` for DLLs that are not loaded by default. However, using `LoadLibrary()` in the event that `GetModuleHandle()` fails is a dangerous strategy as some other thread in the process could `FreeLibrary()` the DLL that you have acquired a handle to via `GetModuleHandle()` (meaning any function addresses that you have acquired via that handle are invalid as the DLL is no longer in memory). Using `LoadLibrary()`, with the subsequent `FreeLibrary()`, is a safer approach as it ensures the DLL won't be unloaded until you `FreeLibrary()` it.

Comment: GetLastError shown Error124, that means could not find the file.